# the preview doesn't show the correct state of the app

Tags: android, android-studio

So I picked up a Udemy course and I'm just starting to get into android development but I noticed a problem. When I open an existing project that I downloaded to edit as a practice lab the preview is not in sync with the actual app. I'll add some pics down below.

[image: This is the preview.]

This is what I actually see when I build and run the app on the emulator

[image: .]

Comment: What Udemy course is it?

Comment: its called complete android n developer course

Comment: Please add the xml of the layout

Comment: i dont know how but i reopened the project just now and it works

Comment: It is a custom view which is part of the Android Support Library. The Preview inside Android Studio not always renders properly for custom views, but that's not something which you can fix (in most cases). So it's not really a programming question in my opinion : )

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to the course; but the [`ActionBarOverlayLayout`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/main/java/android/support/v7/widget/ActionBarOverlayLayout.java) (displayed in the preview) is restricted class, not meant to be used outside of the framework.

Only specific classes can be rendered in the preview, and I suspect the authors of `ActionBarOverlayLayout` did not add this functionality because it is not meant to be seen outside of the framework. This would explain why you only see a blank screen with the name of the class displayed in the editor preview; which is how classes that do not support edit mode are rendered.

As for why the Udemy course uses a restricted class in its layout, I have no clue.